# Perturbation at equilibrium point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, stability-in-odes, nonlinear-analysis

I am studying one system of nonlinear ODE's s.t. the $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(1,0,0)$ is an equilibrium point. On this system I have:
$$(1) x_1,x_2,x_3\geq 0;
\\
(2) x_1+x_2+x_3=1 $$

Well, one author, analysing the stability, added a perturbation $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3>0$ and analyses the state $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(1+\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3)$, proving that $\epsilon_i\to0$.

However, $1+\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2+\epsilon_3>1$.

I did not understand if this state is valid to do the analysis, once it cannot be an initial condition  (if $x_2,x_3$ increase, then $x_1$ might decrease).

I'd like so much to get an explanation.

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1$.  Are you saying the system is not defined when $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \ne 1$, or just that you happen to be interested in solutions that have $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1$?  Are you sure the author required $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \epsilon_3 > 0$? Normally one would not prove stability by looking at just one octant near the equilibrium.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, many thanks for your attention! The equation $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$ is a preliminar, the whole theory is constructed after this, I mean, the only interesting solutions are those that respect this equation. About the other question, yes... The author says "We perturb the equilibrium by adding positive terms...". In fact, negative terms on $x_2,x_3$ do not make sense once the three variables are non-negative... But on $x_1$ yes.

Comment: I don't see how this question can be answered without any reference to the original paper or dynamical system. There could be any number of reasons why the authors have done that. Can you provide links to the source and a definition of the dynamical system considered?

Comment: I think it would have been wiser to use multidirectionnal evalution around the equilibrium state by taking $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3$ just real, not restrictively positive nor negative.

Comment: I thank you all for the comments.